# Truth assignments of a subset of sentence symbols

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I am trying to prove that truth assignments of an infinite subset of sentence symbols are uncountable. I am new to mathematical logic and I am kind of confused. I learned the compactness theorem but I'm not sure how to apply it to this proof.

Comment: Compactness is not useful here (or if it is, it will be a detour). Do you know Cantor's theorem? Can you see that your truth assignments correspond exactly to all the subsets of your infinite set of "sentence symbols"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the $x_n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ are the symbols you're assingning truth values to.
So any such assigmenment is really a function $a: \mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}$, where $a(n)  =1$ if we assign $x_n $ the "true" value and $0$ if we assign it false.

Now in set theory it is shown that this set of functions has size the powerset of $\mathbb{N}$, which is uncountable by [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem).